# JSP - Authentication and Authorization

Tags: java, jsp

I come from an ASP.NET background. In ASP.NET, there is built-in support for users and roles. My question is, does JSP have anything similar or is everything built from scratch? I have not been able to find a good resource to answer this application structure type of question.

Comment: I'll support Trevors answer with the added comment that the Java/JSP community tends to provide itself with tools like this and the Microsoft ASP.NET community will wait for Microsoft to include the feature in the .NET package.

I'd also note that you'll want to talk about what layer you want for users and roles.  Is this at the web server layer or application layer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Servlet API supports user/role based authentication and security. Tomcat (among others) includes [built in support for authenticating](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html) using a variety of sources: xml file, database, LDAP, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider using Spring MVC as a fairly lightweight web framework over JSP. Spring has a very capable authentication & authorization model (right down to method level on objects) using Spring Security (was Acegi) interceptors which can use the sorts of sources that Asaph talks about. You don't need to use Spring MVC in order to use Spring Security if you don't want to.

If you're going to be running your JSPs in a full J2EE server like JBoss, WebLogic or WebSphere there are a whole load of security options that come with such containers incl. integration with AD users and groups.

Comment: I prefer Asaph's answer as he uses the word "LDAP" instead of mentioning only "AD" which is Active Directory, Microsoft LDAP implementation. There are other implementations of LDAP, for example OpenLDAP. I don't see why favouring Microsoft products.